# CCCrypt - Type of expression is ambiguous without more context after iOS 14 update

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios14, commoncrypto

So this morning I updated my OS and XCode to iOS 14, as prompted by the system.

However, when I opened XCode after the update, I encountered the error `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context`. I have not changed the code, and it was working before the update.

Here is the code in question:

```
let ccStatus = CCCrypt(
            CCOperation(kCCEncrypt), // operation
            CCAlgorithm(kAlgorithm), // Algorithm
            CCOptions(kCCOptionPKCS7Padding), // options
            realKey?.withUnsafeBytes{$0.baseAddress?.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt32.self)}, // key //realKey.length, // keylength
            kCCKeySizeAES256,
            realIV?.withUnsafeBytes{$0.baseAddress?.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt32.self)}, // iv
            data?.withUnsafeBytes{$0.baseAddress?.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt32.self)}, // dataIn
            (data?.count ?? 0), // dataInLength,
            cipherData.withUnsafeMutableBytes{$0.baseAddress?.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt32.self)}, // dataOut
            (cipherData.count), // dataOutAvailable
            &outLength) // dataOutMoved
```

I've tried everything I can think of, such as looking for unnecessary spaces, etc... I can't seem to figure this out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so, if anyone finds this later, what did it for me was creating the values before calling the CCCrypt. For example instead of:

```
let ccStatus = CCCrypt(CCOperation(kCCEncrypt),...)
```

I now do:

```
let operation = CCOperation(kCCEncrypt)
//other values needed

let ccStatus = CCCrypt(operation,...)
```